# http response to GET request - working in FF not Chromium

Tags: c, http, network-programming

For fun I'm trying to write a very simple server in C.

When I `send` this response to Firefox it prints out the body "hello, world" but with Chromium it gives me a `Error 100 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED): Unknown error.`

This, I believe, is the relevant code:

```
char *response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language\r\nConnection: Close\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length:20\r\n\r\nhello, world";
    if(send(new_fd, response, strlen(response), 0) == strlen(response)) {
        printf("sent\n");   
    };

    close(new_fd);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as Accepted.

Comment: @Steven You have to wait 15 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) seems to be 12, not 20.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4:

> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an invalid length is received and detected

Doesn't that mean FF violates specs? (Well, you are using HTTP/1.0, so maybe not.)

Comment: That was very silly of me. I assumed the Content-Length was unimportant as long it was big enough. Thank you.

Comment: Just checked with HTTP/1.1 in FF, it does indeed allow for incorrect message length.